# Coefficients of $\prod_{i=1;i \neq j}^{n} (x-i)$

Tags: polynomials, products, stirling-numbers

$1 \leq j \leq n$. Is there a formula that exists to find coefficients for this function? This is as far as i have got it using Sterling numbers of the first kind.. I was wondering if there was a more explicit formula?
$$
\prod_{i=1;i \neq j}^{n} (x-i) = \frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=1;k \neq j}^{n+1} \sum_{2 \leq i_1 \leq ... \leq i_{k-1} \leq n+1} \frac{n!}{i_1 ... i_{k-1}}(-1)^{n-k+1}x^k
$$

Comment: Which interpolation problem are you trying to solve? The coefficients of $\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x-i)$ are given by the Stirling numbers of the first kind (i.e. the elementary symmetric functions of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$).

Comment: I believe the answer is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500579/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-the-coefficients-of-prod-i-1nxx-i?rq=1

Comment: You might want to consider deleting this question, to avoid your future question being judged a duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2495709/stirling-number-of-the-first-kind-expansion